# Using SQL Server Fulltext Search with a Union View

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, union, full-text-search

I have a view which combines two tables via `UNION ALL`. The view is also schemabound, if that matters (`WITH SCHEMABINDING`).

Is it possible to enable fulltext search on this view? I understand that Fulltext Search requires a unique index, but I can't create it because of `UNION`.

Is there another way to make Fulltext Search work on the view?

Answer (score 1):

You could always fulltext search on the component table, and then use other data from that table (id) to get the row back out of the UNION.  Unless, of course, what you're fulltext searching on is composited out of the component rows, in which case this won't help you.